# Is it possible to use timestamp without having to convert it to String in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a query that one of its filters is a date, is it possible to filter in Oracle with something like below?

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dateField = '2014-02-10 15:56:00.000'
```

Or do we always have to convert it to String?

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE dateField = TO_DATE('10/02/2014 15:56:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
```

I'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: People are downvoting for no reason. What's to downvote here? I have a doubt between to options about SQL syntax. Isn't it an Q/A site that experts help others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first query relies on implicit data type conversion which is a really bad thing to do (and is bound to give you problems sooner or later).

The second one properly compares a date to a date and is the right way to do.

If you don't want to type that much, you can use an ANSI SQL timestamp literal:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabela 
WHERE dateField = timestamp '2014-02-10 15:56:00.000';
```

Note the format is required to be ISO in the literal (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd and 24hour time)

Comment: Actually the first query doesn't even work in PL/SQL client. Thanks for the reply, I was missing the timestamp word.

Answer (score 1):

Let me ask you - how is your dateField defined? As string or as date?
If you have defined your field as date - use to_date. If you have a filed like varchar, then you can format the date outside and compare strings.

Comment: It's defined as a Date.

Comment: Well, you have the answer - use date. That's up to your date type.

Comment: But I do not want to use a function such as to date, I want to compare the data straightforwardly.

Comment: The you have to convert your **dateField** to char. Let's see - if the data type don't match you can get a very unexpected result. In fact oracle must ask you to use the correct type and if don't match with the pattern will throw a error. That for you have to use the same type and convert it.

Comment: Check the accepted answer. That is all I need, but thanks for yout time though.

Answer (score 0):

The TO_DATE function converts a date String into an Oracle Date.

If the data in stored as a String, then you can apply any check you want as long as it matches the string comparison.

If the data is stored as a date, then youy have to play with the conversion, to_date or to_char, like you did.